# How can I show an Application page on Feature Activation?

Tags: feature, application-pages, custom-database

We are developing a custom module for SharePoint. The custom module is based upon SmartPart which means we have created UserControls. There was a problem with SmartPart deployment method as it requried to have a UserControls folder on web application root which we handled with a SharePoint Web Application Feature.

This custom module also required a separate database. We could setup the database manually but we also want to automate the database deployment and setup procedure.

Thanks to [Alex](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/how-to-setup-a-database-on-custom-module-installation-or-feature-activation/1592#1592). We decided to create an Application page where we are taking the following parameters:

- Database Server
- Database Name
- Authentication Mode

Behalf of above provided information, we update the web.config with a connectionString. We are working on [creating a database](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/b7762308-475d-4218-9f1b-263116009b83). After this we'll almost done.

> The question I want to ask here is:
>   **The Application page we have how can we show this on Feature activation and
>   when this custom module database
>   successfully created we set the
>   feature activated otherwise it will
>   remain deactivate?**

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what you are trying to achieve.  Am I right in thinking that you want to display a link to an application page when a feature is activated?  If so then where do you want this link to appear?

Comment: @Charles There are two ways in my assumptions: 1) When you click on feature activation button that will redirect you to the application page and where I do the database setup thingy and once it is done successfully I'll activate the feature. 2) When you click on feature activation button feature activated and add up a link in Site Administration for an example "Configuration and Setup" on which I click it takes to the application page. If both are possible then which one should be preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot redirect to an application page when a feature is activated (what would happen if it is activated using STSADM for example or through feature dependencies...).

An alternative approach is to add a Web Part to the default page in the site that contains the configuration options or even better a delegate control that redirect the user to the configuration page if the site is not configured. (I would go for the second one...)

You can also add a link in Sites Settings to your configuration page using Custom Actions.

Comment: Good point on the STSADM issue Wictor.  I answered this question on another thread and I said there would be serious issues with this approach.  This is just one of them.